Why can't I get Firefox to play mp3 audio in one of my apps?
I have 2 web apps that present audio using the <audio> HTML tag. I cannot figure out why one app will play the MP3 file and the other will not. I did get this message from Firefox, buried in some others from a Google doc:

All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

Ok... why?
Note: Yes, there are similar questions asked. I read them already. Most of them are also 5-10 years old.

Doesn't work on Firefox:
<audio controls>
  <source src="/media/my_audio.mp3" />
</audio>



Works fine on Firefox:
<audio controls="">
  <source src="/media/other_audio.mp3">
</audio>

...and also in Chrome:


Other site is working as expected in Firefox:



Things I tried:

CORS? In the non-working version, the audio was originally served from a different domain than the page itself. I tried adding crossorigin to the <audio> tag, adding permissive Access-Control-Allow-<stuff>: * headers via the .htaccess file. I even moved the audio file to the same domain. Nothing.
The file itself? Although it worked in Chrome and Edge, I thought maybe there was some sort of problem with the file. So I re-encoded it with FFmpeg. Nope. I thought maybe, because its duration was about 1 hour, it might be the length that was an issue. So I copied a shorter file (actually one from the "working" example site above). Nope. Actually, the "non-working" file plays just fine in Firefox if I navigate directly to the source URL. So I think it's not the file.
Javascript? In the non-working version I have some buttons to jump forward/backward 10 sec, and I manipulate the audio position in JS. I don't see why that would matter, but maybe?
JS #2: The <audio> tag and the rest of that page are created in JS and then added to the page container (no framework, just me). Again, doesn't make sense why that would be an issue, but maybe?
I added the Content-Type: "audio/mpeg" header to .htaccess where the audio is served, but that also didn't help. Tried adding the MIME type to the source tag in HTML, too.

First 40 bytes of the MP3:

FF FB 90 44  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  58 69 6E 67


Supposedly FF FB are magic numbers for MP3 (without ID3v2 metadata). However, I did try a few other MP3s with the page, and none worked. At least one of the others did start with the 3 bytes ID3.
More complete HTML looks like this:
Everything inside #content is being created in JS using document.createElement('template') and then setting innerHTML. The audio URL is inserted via $interview.audio_path. The iframe shows a Google document for editing. This whole #interview-editor element is then added to #content's children.
<body>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="interview-editor" class="right-sidebar">
            <div id="interview-audio">
                <a data-action="replay_30" class="btn-large">30</a>
                <a data-action="replay_10" class="btn-large">10</a>
                <a data-action="replay_5" class="btn-large">5</a>
                <audio id="audio-control" controls src="${interview.audio_path}"></audio>
                <!-- above is what i did originally, then tried this variation as well
                <audio id="audio-control" controls>
                    <source src="${interview.audio_path}">
                </audio> -->
                <a data-action="forward_5" class="btn-large">5</a>
                <a data-action="forward_10" class="btn-large">10</a>
                <a data-action="forward_30" class="btn-large">30</a>
            </div>

            <div id="interview-transcript">
                <iframe src="${interview.text_path}" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

There is some JS hooked up to the 6 a.btn-large elements to jump backward and forward in the audio:
    function onButtonClick(btn) {
        // action can be close or one of the audio skip buttons
        const action = btn.dataset.action;

        if (action.startsWith("replay") || action.startsWith("forward")) {
            let [direction, amount] = action.split("_");
            amount = Number(amount);
            if (direction === "replay") amount *= -1
            console.log(`audio seek: ${amount}`);
            const audioControl = document.getElementById("audio-control");
            audioControl.currentTime += amount;
        } else {
            console.error(`error: unknown action ${action}`);
        }
    }


"Note: Yes, there are similar questions asked. I read them already. Most of them are also 5-10 years old."  The age of the question/answer doesn't really matter if it's still relevant.  Browsers have been playing MP3 audio natively for like, 15 years now.

Whatever the problem is is unrelated to your code shown here.  You probably don't have an MP3 file, but something else.  Or, you're using a build of Firefox that has third-party codecs disabled.

Open your audio file in a hex editor and tell us its first 40 bytes to make sure it really is MPEG 1 audio layer III (instead of just forcing your server to tell so). If its first 3 bytes are ID3 then try to seek to a position that doesn't look that much like text anymore (but also is not entirely bytes of value 00). Furthermore try to provide a minimal but full example of your HTML file, preferably without JS - maybe it then also works for you already and you got more hints to pinpoint the culprit.

@AmigoJack posted updates. I can post hex of a few other mp3s too.  All the audio i've tried does play in FF if I navigate directly to the source url. I downloaded FF for windows directly from FF's site, no special builds or anything that I can imagine.

Yes, that's at least MPEG what you have, so the file(s) are not the issue. Start from scratch without any JS - who knows in which other browser engines it doesn't work, too. Create code that would also work without JS (as in: write complete HTML with a proper <source src= value not being a template AND AFTERWARDS try replacing that content with JS). How do you assert this is all rendered correctly and in-time for Firefox? Do you look for errors and exceptions on what could go wrong executing JS? BTW: Firefox' official abbreviation is "Fx".

A page with only the audio tag does seem to work. I also tried constructing the audio element using new Audio(), setting the properties, then adding it, but that didn't work. I guess the issue must have something to do with JS.

I was able to make my page work with Firefox by delaying setting <audio>'s src attribute until after the new node (#interview-editor) was actually inserted into the page's DOM.
I did not have to take this step on Chrome, Edge, or Safari.
